# Curry Data getting mangled

Tags: javascript, currying

I am using a curry 3 to extract two datasets and in the case of the second which uses the same intermediate function, the data gets mangled and I cannot determine why. So using two intermediates such that `var final function = funName(true)(true)` on a curry 3 when I execute the final parameter of the second call the data is mangled and incorrect, almost like the params were not cleared from the call to final of the first data request.

```
function curry3( func ) {
  return function( first ) {
    return function( second ) {
      return function( third ) {
        return function( fourth ) {
          return func( first, second, third, fourth );
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: function curry3( func ) {
    return function( first ) {
     return function( second ) {
      return function( third ) {
       return function( fourth ) {
        return func( first, second, third, fourth );
       };
      };
     };
    };
   };

Comment: Can you post your some actual code or sample?

Comment: This is much worse than a callback hell.

Comment: for some reason it won't let me post the code, it says something of only one @user can be notified at a time

Comment: @adriani6, that is a standard curry formation

Comment: ok can you add into comment, will modify then.

Comment: var getRecordsCurried = _.curriedTemplates().getRecordsCurry3()( searchModule )( 'invoice' );

Comment: var searchObjectRunMappedParamsCurried = _.curriedTemplates().getSearchObjectRunMappedCurry3()( true )( false );

Comment: var getCustomers = _.pipeline( getRecordsCurried, searchObjectRunMappedParamsCurried );

Comment: var invoicesWithCustomers = getCustomers( query.getColumnsAndFilters() );

Comment: Ok that is the curry setup and call to final, the second time I use the final the data is magled

Comment: curriedTemplates: function() {
    return {
     getRecordsCurry3                : function() {
      return _.curry3( _.reOrderArgs( _.NSSearchCreateCurried, [ 1, 2, 4 ] ) );
     }
     , getSearchObjectRunMappedCurry3: function() {
      return _.curry3( _.reOrderArgs( _.NSSearchObjectRunMapped, [ 2, 3, 1 ] ) );
     }
    }
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the curry was fine but the method I used to re-order the args of the target method for the curry is retaining some state. Once removed it worked fine, thanks for all your help.